# Generating Google doc from template, needing to link within email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms, google-docs-api

I have sections of Google scripts below that I have set to generate a new document from a template with variables added from a Google form.

The new document is then converted to a PDF and emailed as an attachment.

What I now also want to do is include a hyperlink to the Google document itself.

I can see DocumentApp.openByUrl is a possible function but just don't know how to apply it.

**autoFillGoogleDocFromForm**

```
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Channel = e.values[1];
  var Name = e.values[2];;
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID'); 
  
  var folder = createChannelFolder(); // 1st modification point
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Channel + ',' + Name, folder); 
  var newId = copy.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId); 

  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', Timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{Channel}}', Channel);  
  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', Name);
         
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

**Send html email**

```
  //Setup embedded image.
  var imgID = "IMAGEID"
  var imageURL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id="+imgID;
  var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp
                         .fetch(imageURL)
                         .getBlob()
                         .setName("imageblob");
  var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html");
  body.Name = Name;
  body.Channel = Channel;
  var Blob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var Email = Email;
  var subject = 'Submitted'; 
  var values = e.values;
    GmailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body.evaluate().getContent(),
      inlineImages:
      {
        imageblob: imageBlob},
      attachments: [{
      fileName: Channel + ".pdf",
      content: Blob.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"}]
});                                         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`getUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#geturl).

I don't know how those two blocks of code are related or where you want to include the URL, but the example in the link above should be pretty helpful. Something like

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId);
var url = doc.getUrl();
```

Comment: I can get the URL and include it within an .html file which is then sent with the function GmailApp.sendEmail , it just seems there isn't an obvious means of hyperlinking the URL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @EwanFarry

Comment: Hi, no problem any more, I must have added a malformed hyperlink. 

I had convinved myself that the scriptlet I had <?= newFileUrl ?> wasn't something you could link to, but it works;

<a href=" <?= newFileUrl ?> ">Click Here</a>